# iOS detect when point is in rect

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, cgrect, cgpoint

I am utilizing a split view controller when the user can select an item out of the master view and drag it over to the detail view and place it. While the user is dragging, a UIView appears at the bottom of the detail view where they can drag the item if they change their mind mid-drag and want to remove it. I am having troubles detecting when the touch is in the UIView to remove. Here is what I have so far:

Code that is executed when the user selects the item in the master controller.

MasterViewController:

```
    // Create pointer to window
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;

    // Create draggable view
    self.draggableImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageView.image];

    // Adapt to orientation
    [self.draggableImageView rotateToOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];

    // Hide detail calloutview if there is one
    [self.detailViewController hideCalloutView:NO];

    // Add drag-view to window
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view.window];
    [self.draggableImageView setCenter:location];
    [window addSubview:[self draggableImageView]];

    // Animate the marker to jump up
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.10
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         // Move the marker up
                         [self.draggableImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x + 75.0f, location.y)];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

    // Show our remove marker view
    [self.detailViewController showRemoveMarkerView];
```

While the user is dragging, a method in the detail view controller is being called with the updated point and this is the code within that method:

```
- (void)pointForMarkerDidChange:(UIImageView *)imageView atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    NSLog(@"Point for Marker Did Change, point = %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointMake(point.x - 75.0f, point.y)));

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
    CGRect removeMarkerFrame = [window convertRect:self.removeMarkerView.frame fromView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(removeMarkerFrame, point)) {

        NSLog(@"YES");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I changed up the following code and it works now.

```
- (void)pointForMarkerDidChange:(UIImageView *)imageView atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
    CGRect removeMarkerFrame = [self.removeMarkerView convertRect:self.removeMarkerView.round.frame toView:self.view];
    CGPoint point2 = [window convertPoint:point toView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(removeMarkerFrame, point2)) {

        NSLog(@"YES");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are `removeMarkerView` and `draggableImageView` both in the same super view? Why don't you hit test the `removeMarkerView`  From the gesture?

Comment: The removeMarkerView superview is the mapView that it is added as a subview and the UIWindow is the superview for the draggableImageView

Comment: Fixed the problem. See my edit.